# Fluent NHibernate Mapping is set to AllDeleteOrphan but is still trying to null the foreign key in the DB

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm getting an error with NHibernate when I try to perfrom a ISession.Delete on any table with a One to Many relationship.

NHibernate is trying to set the foreign key to the parent table in the child table to null, rather than just deleting the child table row.

Here is my domain:

```
public class Parent
{

    public Parent()
    {
        _children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SimpleString { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SimpleDateTime { get; set; }

    private IList<Child> _children;
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }
    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(child);
    }
}


public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SimpleString { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SimpleDateTime { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I have set-up the Fluent NHibernate mappings as follows:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.SimpleString);
        Map(x => x.SimpleDateTime);

        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumn("ParentId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);

    }
}

public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.SimpleString);
        Map(x => x.SimpleDateTime);
        References(x => x.Parent).Not.Nullable().Column("ParentId").Cascade.All().Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

I've told NHibernate to `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()` but it's still trying to set the ParentId foriegn key to null here is the test I setup:

```
public void Delete_GivenTableWithChildren_WillBeDeletedFromDB()
{
    int id;
    using (var createSession = MsSqlSessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        var parent = new Parent();
        parent.AddChild(new Child { SimpleString = "new child from UI" });

        using (var trx = createSession.BeginTransaction())
        {
            createSession.Save(parent);
            trx.Commit();
            id = parent.Id;
        }
    }

    using (var firstGetSession = MsSqlSessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        var result = firstGetSession.Get<Parent>(id);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }

    using (var deleteSession = MsSqlSessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var trx = deleteSession.BeginTransaction())
        {
            deleteSession.Delete("from " + typeof(Parent).Name + " o where o.Id = :Id", id, NHibernateUtil.Int32);
            trx.Commit();
        }
    }

    using (var session = MsSqlSessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        var result = session.Get<Parent>(id);
        Assert.IsNull(result);
    }
}
```

Which is failing on the `deleteSession.Delete` line after attempting the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [Child] SET ParentId = null WHERE ParentId = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=5
```

with:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not delete collection: [SaveUpdateOrCopyTesting.Parent.Children#5][SQL: UPDATE [Child] SET ParentId = null WHERE ParentId = @p0]
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParentId', table 'SaveUpdateCopyTestingDB.dbo.Child'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong in my mappings, or know of a way to stop NHibernate from attempting to null the foreign key id?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try setting .Inverse() on the ParentMap's HasMany, so it looks like:

```
HasMany(x => x.Children)
        .Not.LazyLoad()
        .KeyColumn("ParentId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse()
        .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

Comment: Legend.. thank you.. I thought that Inverse would mean that Saves would fail, as it would try to insert into the Child record before it inserted into the Parent record. Just ran full Crud tests and all cascades work a treat.. thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help. There's a decent SO thread on the use of inverse if it helps better explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061179/when-to-use-inverse-false-on-nhibernate-hibernate-onetomany-relationships

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if cascade works if you delete with HQL.

Try this:

```
var parent = deleteSession.Load<Parent>(id)
deleteSession.Delete(parent);
```

It's a pity that you don't have lazy loading. `Load` would not need the entity to be read from the database, it would just create a proxy in memory.

Comment: Hi, tried the above and it produces the same Sql statements as before, ultimately resulting in the same constraint exception being raised by the DB.  

"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParentId', table 'SaveUpdateCopyTestingDB.dbo.Child'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated."  

Any other ideas?