# Hibernate Bidirectional Assocation

Tags: hibernate, bidirectional

What is the difference between `inverse="true"` and `constrained="true"`.

Aren't both used to make the association bidirectional? 
Also aren't both adding a foreign key constraint linking the primary key in the 2 tables?

I am confused. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

constrained is used for lazy loading of one-to-one relations. Because they are implemented by shared primary keys, NHibernate doesn't know if there is a record in the other table before it fetched it. With constrained you tell NHibernate that there is always a record expected, so it can create a proxy. See [this blog post from Ayende Rahien](https://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one).

With inverse, you tell NHibernate that a one-to-many relation is already stored by the many side, so it doesn't need to store the collection on the one side. I tried to explain it here: [When to use inverse=false on NHibernate / Hibernate OneToMany relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061179/when-to-use-inverse-false-on-nhibernate-hibernate-onetomany-relationships/4896221#4896221)